# How can I change the value of the fields for a generated POJO using Lombok?

Tags: java, lombok, dto, pojo

I'm using Lombok for POJOs generation, so how can I change the value of the fields?

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder(toBuilder = true, builderClassName = "builder")
public class Student{
  String name;
  String age;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Value creates the immutable object. you can't change the value of field once object initialised. You can create new object by changing specific property by using toBuilder method. e.g:

```
Student s1 = Student.builder()
            .name("Sam")
            .age("11")
            .build();

Student s2 =s1.toBuilder()
              .age("12")
              .build();
```

Or you need to remove @Value annotation and add @Data. Then you can use setter for the property.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this annotation in the above your pojo class `@Builder(toBuilder = true)`

```
Student student1 = Student.builder()
  .name("foo")
  .id(1)
  .build();

Student.StudentBuilder studentBuilder = student1.toBuilder();
```

also you can use just `@Data` annotation instead of `@NoArgConstructor`, `@AllArgConstructor`, because `@Data` annotation completed them.
if you have a problem,which `@Data` annotation, generally this problem occur when using relationship entity, if so than you can use `@ToString.Exclude` annotation in the relationship entity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `@Getter` and `@Setter` just before `Steudent`. Then you can change the value of a field automatically by `setName(value)`.
Example:

```java
Steudent s = new Student();
s.setName("toto");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Student Student = Student.builder()
                .name("Sam")
                .age("11")
                .build();
```